# retrieving data with AngularFire

Tags: angular, angularfire

I have a firebase collection thatcontains document. I also have an Angular 8 app configured with AngularFireModule and AngularFirestoreModule. In my component I want to retrieve all documents of a collection. This is a code snippet:

```
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.rowData = this.firestore
      .collection("invoices")
      .get()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

If I render the component, I get no error messages and also no data. The output to the console is

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Inspecting the network tab shows there are requests going out to https://google.firestore.com but the response contains no data.
I'm not sure what part of the quickstart (https://github.com/angular/angularfire) I missed. Although I do not use the Async pipe in the template to resolve the Observer from  AngularFire, this should work as well.

relevant package.json entries:

```
"@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
"@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
"firebase": "^7.9.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to subscribe to `valueChanges` or `snapshotChanges` instead of `get`

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data